# Ошибка при обновлении VS Code

Tags: windows, visual-studio-code

При попытке перезапустить VS Code для обновления получаю следующую ошибку:
[image: Ошибка]

ОС: Windows 7

Как бороться с данной проблемой?

Comment: Может проблема в совместимости? ПК 32бит, а VS Code на 64бит?

Comment: @Sherlock, неа ПК тоже 64бит. При этом сама программа работает отлично, ошибка только при перезапуске для обновления

Comment: Попробуйте тут почитать https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/57028

Comment: @karmik, читал и не раз, толкового там нету

Comment: Память проверяли, с ней точно всё нормально?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решилась путём установки Microsoft Visual C++ 2015-2019. 
Спасибо всем, кто заглянул на огонёк ;)